# Mysql grant all privileges to a user on everywhere

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

In my windows forms application I use Mysql to get data. (I use MySql.Data.dll)

Here is my connection string:

```
server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;user id=user_name;Password=userpass;database=products
```

When I want use my application on a computer, I must add computer's ip to remote mysql connection on cpanel. I want grant all privileges (on every IP) to user which I use on my connection string.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try giving the user a "Super User" privileges;

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

to add password into the query;

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'%' identified by 'userpass';
```

Comment: How can I add password into the sql query

Comment: It should be done on creation of the user; `CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: or use `grant all privileges on mydb.* to user_name@'%'identified by 'password';` will update answer accordingly

Comment: Does the grant command create the user? If not then how does defining the password work there?

Answer (score -1):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'Hello@123' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I think you may be swirling up the query up the loo, mainly the password with the host. As in `'root'@'Hello@123'` should be `'root'@'localhost'` and to set the password, `IDENTIFIED BY  'Hello@123';` Or do you have an explanation to clear this up? [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html).